# Как получить актуальную дату и сравнить ее

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Вопросов несколько.

Описание:
В Google sheets, apps script
Я с помощью цикла проверяю диапазон и ищу строку. Если она содержит имя, то я получаю его позицию в диапазоне. Рядом с этим именем в соседнем столбце есть дата соответствующая, и я с помощью `getRange()` получаю дату, которая соответствует найденному имени (строке). Дальше в отдельном условии за пределами цикла мне нужно сравнить, равняется ли дата, полученная в цикле, дате полученной в виде объекта в сценарии.
Вот тут вопросы:

1. Как получить актуальную date, но в формате `дд.мм.гггг` без времени. То есть чтобы было все как в обычном объекте new data, но без `мин.сек.милсек`.
2. Как сравнить в if дату актуальную в формате `дд.мм.гггг` с датой которую я получил в результате выполнения цикла. Дату из цикла нужно тоже желательно сделать `дд.мм.гггг`, как я понимаю.

Код

```js
function timeDay() {
    var list1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Контроль");
    var list2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Работники/данные/списки");
    var infmail = list2.getRange(1, 4, 100, 1).getValues();
    // Logger.log(infmail);
    var infNameTime = list1.getRange(1, 4, 100, 1).getValues();
    var infNameTime2 = list1.getRange(3, 4, 100, 1).getValues();
    //Logger.log(infNameTime);



    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var date = new Date(); //получаю дату


    //Logger.log(date);

    var malpz;
    var mal = [];
    var maillist = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < infmail.length; i++) {
        if (infmail[i].indexOf(email) !== -1) {
            mal.push([i + 1]);
            maillist.push(infmail[i]);
            malpz = i + 1;
        }
    }
    //Logger.log(malpz);
    //Logger.log(mal);
    //Logger.log(maillist);
    var nameMail = list2.getRange(malpz, 2).getValues();
    //Logger.log(nameMail);


    var dd;
    var tt;
    var namepz = [];
    var namelist = [];
    for (var b = 0; b < infNameTime.length; b++) {
        if (infNameTime[b][0].indexOf(nameMail) !== -1) {
            namepz.push([b + 1]);
            namelist.push(infNameTime[b]);
            tt = b + 1;
            dd = list1.getRange(tt, 3).getValue();
```

Этой строкой я  получаю дату актуальную, но хочу получить в том формате как описал выше

```
var date = new Date();
```

А в этой строке находится дата относительно имени

```
dd = list1.getRange(tt,3).getValue();
```

Я ее получаю из строки в таком же формате как и

```
var date = new Date();
```

Но хочу получить в формате как описал выше, а потом применить условие, в ходе которого if сравнит и выполнит блок. Очень важно, чтобы даты не имели часов, минут, секунд, миллисекунд. По логике должны сравниваться только число, месяц, год.

Comment: прикрепите пожалуйста код который вы используете для работы с датой

Comment: @Andrew, я прикрепил код, с маленьким пояснением. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - это сравнить две даты как числа

```js
console.log(date1.getTime() === date2.getTime());
```

Сравнение по дням для Apps Script

```js
const roundDate_ = 
  (date) => 
    Utilities.formatDate(date, 'Europe/Moscow', 'yyyy-MM-dd');

console.log(roundDate_(date1) === roundDate_(date2));
```

Сравнение по по формату для Apps Script

```js
const roundDateFormat_ = 
  (date, format) => 
    Utilities.formatDate(date, 'Europe/Moscow', format);

// сравнивает только по месяцам
console.log(roundDate_(date1, 'yyyy-MM') === roundDate_(date2, 'yyyy-MM'));
```

Сравнение для JS вообще (*добавлено*)

```js
const roundDate_ = 
  (date) => 
    new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru-RU').format(date);

console.log(roundDate_(date1) === roundDate_(date2));
```

и т.д. и т.п.

Для большого количества сравнений метод `Utilities.formatDate` может "провисать по времени". Тогда лучше использовать родные методы округления дат. Например,

```js
const roundDate_ = date => {
  const date_ = new Date(date);
  date_.setHours(0 ,0 ,0 , 0);
  return date_;
}
```

Далее сравнение проводить через `getTime()` как числа.

Обращайте внимание на часовые пояса проекта и Таблицы, они могут приводить к ошибкам смещения часового пояса в расчетах.